# How to set resolve path for image-width?

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I have a LESS file that refers to an absolute location (it needs to be absolute or grunt-usemin won't parse it properly), but this causes the less compiler to not be able to resolve the image when processing `image-width()`.

***/client/app/app.less***

```
// logo is located at /client/assets/images/ but "/client" is the 
// web root, which is why the absolute reference is "/assets/images"
@logo-url: '/assets/images/web-header-111_253x45.gif';
@logo-width: image-width(@logo-url);
@logo-height: image-height(@logo-url);

.web-header {
    width: @logo-width;
    height: @logo-height;
    background: url(@logo-url);
}
```

***/gruntfile.js***

```
  grunt.initConfig({

    /* TRIMMED */

    less: {
      options: {
      },
      server: {
        files: [{
          src: ['client/app/app.less'],
          dest: '.tmp/app/app.css'
        }]
      }
    }

    /* TRIMMED */
  });
```

The above will throw the following build error:

```
Warning: Running "less:server" (less) task
>> RuntimeError: error evaluating function `image-width`: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\git\www-project\client\app\assets\images\web-header-111_2
53x45.gif' in client\app\app.less on line 26, column 14:
>> 25 @logo-url: '/assets/images/web-header-111_253x45.gif';
>> 26 @logo-width: image-width(@logo-url);
>> 27 @logo-height: image-height(@logo-url);
Warning: Error compiling client/app/app.less Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

**Question:** What can I set to make image-width(...) resolve relative to the C:\git\www-project\client directory rather than the directory containing app.less?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I set both an absolute URL path & calculate a relative file path, then the `image-width(...)` path can be resolved with no problem.

```
// logo is located at /client/assets/images/ but "/client" is the 
// web root, which is why the absolute reference is "/assets/images"
@root: '..';
@logo-url: '/assets/images/web-header-111_253x45.gif';
@logo-path: '@{root}@{logo-url}';
@logo-width: image-width(@logo-path);
@logo-height: image-height(@logo-path);

.web-header {
    width: @logo-width;
    height: @logo-height;
    background: url(@logo-url);
}
```